# Why dose (copy) property and (strong) property init differently?

Tags: objective-c

When code init method, a `(copy)` property should be assigned like

```
_foo = [foo copy];
```

but for a `(strong)` property just assign it:

```
_bar = bar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `strong` property, the variable (var `_bar`) itself is `strong`, therefore the assignment is enough to create a strong reference.

The copying is not done automatically though. There are no `copy` variables, therefore `copy` must be called explicitly.

Just a few years ago, before Automatic Reference Counting was introduced, the `strong` assignment used to be:

```
_bar = [bar retain];
```

but that was automatized in ARC and nowadays we need only

```
_bar = bar;
```

By the way, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with directly assigning to property:

```
self.bar = bar;
```

for both `copy` and `strong` properties. The access through ivar `_bar` is only necessary if your setters read other properties which could be uninitialized yet.